# How to get debug output for Jupyter Notebook ContentManager code

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm writing a ContentsManager for Jupyter-Notebook to store data on a local OpenStack SwiftStore.  I'm taking [S3Contents](https://github.com/danielfrg/s3contents) as my starting point.

I have a basic framework that will connect & create a container if it doesn't exist.... however before I go any further, I need to start creating unit tests.

My question is how do I see the DEBUG output?

If I have a method that starts:

```
def get(self, path, content=True, type=None, format=None):
    """Retrieve an object from the store, named in 'path'
    """
    self.log.debug("SwiftContents[swiftmanager]: get '%s', path)
```

.... how do I see the output `SwiftContents[swiftmanager]: get '\foo\bar'`?

Also, what's the testing framework used by notebooks?

```
class SwiftContentsManager(ContentsManager):
    # Initialise the instance
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SwiftContentsManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.swiftfs = SwiftFS(log=self.log)
```

It looks a bit like `unittest`, except it has `setUp` rather than `startUp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run tests: `nosetests path/to/tests/test_foo.py`

To run tests, and see what it's actually doing: `nosetests -v path/to/tests/test_foo.py`

To run tests, see what it's actually doing, **and** see the debug output: `nosetests -v --debug path/to/tests/test_foo.py`

For more information, see http://pythontesting.net/framework/nose/nose-introduction/